# Converges of a series made of another series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. It means that the sequence of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence, and it means that $s_n=\sum_{k=n}^{n^2}a_k$ converges against zero.

Does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n$ converge? I do not see a reason for it to converge, so I tried to find a good example of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n$ diverges, but have not so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Anything works... say $a_n=1/n^2$. Which examples did you check before posting this?

Comment: @Did a geometric series.

Comment: Ha. OK. But there are other beasts in the world of series...

Comment: @Did Thanks for the hint, I tried to expand on it above.

Comment: @SergeyZykov In your edit, how do you get the $n^4-n^2+1$ factor? You only have $n^2-n+1$ terms. The main issue (that prevents convergence) is that $a_n=1/n^2$ appears many times in $\sum_1^\infty s_n$: it is in $s_{\sqrt{n}}, s_{\sqrt{n}+1, \dots, s_n}$, i.e. roughly $n$ times.

Comment: (Another argument that shows you edited content has a flw: $s_n$ *does* converge to zero, as you do state a bit before at the beginning of your question.)

Comment: @ClementC. you are right.